# State is not updating immediately in React.js

Tags: reactjs

I have state like below

```
state = { 
        name: false,
        email: false,
        address: false,
        telephone_no: false,
        image: false,
    }
```

I have a method like below

```
  makeInputBox = value => {
        Object.keys(this.state).map(item => {
                if(item === value){
                    this.setState({[item]:true},
                        () => console.log(this.state));
                } else {
                    this.setState({[item]:false},
                        () => console.log(this.state));
                }
            }
        );
    }
```

I have some JSX like below

```
render() { 
    return (<tr key={this.props.index}>
                <td className="ui header data_type">
                    { this.props.item === 'name'? 'Name':null }
                    { this.props.item === 'email'? 'Email':null }
                    { this.props.item === 'address'? 'Address':null }
                    { this.props.item === 'telephone_no'? 'Telephone No':null }
                    { this.props.item === 'image'? 'Photo':null }
                </td>
            <td>
                { 
                    this.state[this.props.item] ? 
                    <input type="text"/> : 
                    <span className="edit" onClick={()=>this.makeInputBox(this.props.item)}>                                                   
                    Edit</span> 
                }
            </td></tr>
            );
}
```

I am getting console output like below

```
{name: false, email: false, address: false, telephone_no: true, image: false}
{name: false, email: false, address: false, telephone_no: true, image: false}
{name: false, email: false, address: false, telephone_no: true, image: false}
{name: false, email: false, address: false, telephone_no: true, image: false}
{name: false, email: false, address: false, telephone_no: true, image: false}
```

My HTML is look like below

[image]

State is changing its value to `true` and `false` but it is not reflecting in `JSX`.

What is the issue here ?

Comment: Please post full code? Where you put your JSX code?

Comment: Firstly, `map()` is for returning a new array, not iterating over an array. Use `forEach()` or a simple for loop. Secondly, don't call `setState()` on every loop, it's very inefficient. Construct the object fully, then put all the values into state with one `setState()` call. Thirdly, what does "it is not reflecting in the JSX" mean? JSX is your React code. Do you mean it's not reflecting in the actual app?

Comment: Thanks @HenokTesfaye. I added more code. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Jayce444. I'll follow your instruction but sample code is helpful in this regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't you think this

```
  makeInputBox = value => {
    Object.keys(this.state).map(item => {
      if (item === value) {
        this.setState({ [item]: true }, () => console.log(this.state));
      } else {
        this.setState({ [item]: false }, () => console.log(this.state));
      }
    });
  };
```

the same thing as this?

```
  makeInputBox = value => {
    this.setState({
      [value]: true
    });
  };
```

If you want to toggle the state for a value you could try:

```
  makeInputBox = value => {
    this.setState((currentState) => {
      [value]: !currentState[value]
    });
  };
```

`setState` merges the changes you pass to it in the current state. You just have to call it with the changes you want.

Comment: To answer exactly to your question:
_Think of setState() as a request rather than an immediate command to update the component. For better perceived performance, React may delay it, and then update several components in a single pass. React does not guarantee that the state changes are applied immediately._ from [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it can work with only one call to setState in your makeInputBox function:

```
let state = Object.assign({}, this.state);

// Everybody to false
Object.keys(state).forEach(v => state[v] = false)

// es6 set wanted value to true and only one call to setState
this.setState({...state, [value]:true}, console.log(this.state))
```